# Python - Is it possible to create a list containing sets within it?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

Is it possible to create a list containing sets within it?

This code is not compiling ( should I use a dictionary of sets instead? )

```
v = []

v.append(set(3, 2))

v[2] = set()

v[2].append(3, 1)
```

I am trying to do a graph traversal using a quasi Dijkstra's Algorithm.
I am trying to store the adjacency list in sets within a list.
Is this the right approach or should I use another data structure?

I am trying to convert the following C++ into Python. what data structure can I use for the Vector?

```
        long long leastTimeToInterview (int n, int k, int m)
    {
       vector<set<pair<int, int>>> v (n + 1); // first = time, second = stop #

       while (m--) {
          int i, j, t; cin >> i >> j >> t;
          v[i].insert ({ t, j });
          v[j].insert ({ t, i });
       }

       set<pair<int, int>> s ({ { 0,1 } });
       unordered_set<int> done;
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. But `[2]` doesn't exist as an index when your list only contains a single item at index `0`, which happens to be a `set`

Comment: Please work through basic tutorials on the language features you're trying to use.  This will solve your specific problems, and give you a wider understanding of the language.

Comment: Yes I understand but in C++ you can have a vector v and start assigning it v[i] right away as per the code block above.  What is the equivalent data structure of vector in Python where I can use this kind of functionality?

Comment: @fynx take a look at this [python_in_built_ds_page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 4):

> set(3, 2)

That's not how you define a set. The set constructor only takes one argument.

Instead use:

```
v = []
v.append({3, 2})
print(v)
```

Output:

```
[{2, 3}]
```

As an alternative, you can pass any iterable to the set constructor:

```
set((3, 2))
set([3, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks, so what your saying is that all the 3 statements below are equivalent?
 
   v = []
 
   v.append({3, 2})
 
   v.append(set([3, 1]))
 
   v.append(set((1, 3)))

Comment: @fynx exactly, ``{3, 2} == set([3, 1] == set((1, 3))``

Comment: Ok Thanks, but I am trying to convert C++ code which uses vectors into Python, so can I use a List for this purpose?
here is the code I am trying to convert:
( The code does not format properly here so I will add it up above)

Comment: @fynx sets are not ordered, so in your case, you should use a list of list or a list of tuples